# Why is Python 3.6.3 csv.read() adding data out of sequence

Tags: python-3.x

--Noobe  Here--

I have a table of data as displayed below which is stored in a file.

[image: Input Data]

It is processed by the below code snippet. All 
looks good until the last entry in the table is
reached and then the code suddenly starts
appending earlier data read from the input file.
I have looked for extraneous characters in the
input data but find nothing that alerts me.

```
with open('barometer.txt', 'r') as pressure:

    formatted_file = csv.reader(pressure, delimiter = ',')    
    for line in formatted_file:
        print (line)
```

The resulting output of the above code snippet is:

[image: Print Output Data]

I suspect a spurious character at the end of the
input file but cannot seem to locate it. Any insight
is greatly appreciated.

Mel Blanchard

Comment: Please post the csv file as text. I got a really strange error when I tried to feed your screenshot into a csv reader...

Comment: pressure, 1011536, *nixepochtime, 1525433168299
  pressure, 1011526, *nixepochtime, 1525433048051
  pressure, 1011521, *nixepochtime, 1525432927808
  pressure, 1011510, *nixepochtime, 1525432807594
  pressure, 1011485, *nixepochtime, 1525432687379
  pressure, 1011465, *nixepochtime, 1525432567158
  pressure, 1011452, *nixepochtime, 1525432446813
  pressure, 1011428, *nixepochtime, 1525432369208
  pressure, 1011403, *nixepochtime, 1525432206811
  pressure, 1011348, *nixepochtime, 1525432109999